# Python SciPy Possible cases of n choose k

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, combinations

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
# OR !
a = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six']
```

In this situation, I just want to know ALL possible combinations; choose *k* elements among **a**. If I use `b = scipy.misc.comb(a, 1)`, it shows:

```
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

where b<sub>i</sub> is just a<sub>i</sub> choose 1. And it doesn't work if **a** is an array of strings.

What I really wanted is:

```
b = [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6]]
# OR !
b = [['one'], ['two'], ['three'], ['four'], ['five'], ['six']]
```

which means, the possible set of 1 chosen element among elements in the array **a**

It is very easy if I use MATLAB. But I'm trying to use SciPy stack.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Any reason for using `scipy` and not `itertools` for this particular problem?

Looking into `itertools.combinations` or `itertools.permutations` may provide a more adequate solution.

Comment: Wow. Thanks a lot. I am new to Python for science & math. So it's the first time I've heard of itertools.

Answer (score 12):

Here is a more complete answer.
You should use `itertools.combinations` and not the `itertools.permutations` as combination is very different from permutation.

For instance if you needed all the two element combinations of an array such as `[1,2,3,5]` the following code will produce the result that you want (equivalent of `nchoosek` in Matlab). See more examples [from this source](http://thomas-cokelaer.info/blog/2012/11/how-do-use-itertools-in-python-to-build-permutation-or-combination/).

```
>>> import itertools
>>> all_combos = list(itertools.combinations([1,2,3,5], 2))
>>> print all_combos
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 5), (2, 3), (2, 5), (3, 5)]
```

if You would like all the combinations as a 2d array just convert the tuple list to a numpy array using the following command:

```
>>> all_combos = np.array(list(itertools.combinations([1,2,3,5], 2)))
>>> print all_combos
[[1 2]
 [1 3]
 [1 5]
 [2 3]
 [2 5]
 [3 5]]
```