# Translate Matlab's nchoosek to Python

Tags: python, combinations

I want to translate code from Matlab to Python, but I can't find a Python equivalent for `nchoosek`. This is the code:

```
ber_c = nchoosek(n,e+1)*p.^(e+1)
```

and I've made this:

```
ber_c = comb(n, e + 1)*p**(e+1)
```

Comment: Do you have the `scipy` library available? If so, [`scipy.misc.comb`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/generated/scipy.misc.comb.html) may be what you need.

Comment: Are you using `nchoosek` to get the number of combinations, or the array of the actual combinations? (I'm guessing the former, but it would be good to be sure.)

Comment: i call scipy.misc but i have 4 options:  common, doccer, pilutil and setup

Comment: So `scipy.misc.comb` should be a good match for `nchoosek`, though if you want exact integers, you'll want to use `comb(n, e+1, exact=True)`. It sounds as though you already have an answer to your question. What's the problem that you're encountering? E.g., if you're getting a particular Python exception, please show the traceback. If you're getting wrong results, show the results you got and those you expected.

Comment: Also, if you need exact results and performance is the issue, a home-built `nchoosek` using `math.factorial` (as suggested by @blue_note) would likely be more efficient than the version from `SciPy`.

Comment: ber_c = math.factorial(n, e + 1*p**(e+1))

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'list' and 'float' is the error i have

Comment: Can you add that information to the question, along with the values of `p`, `e` that you're using? You may want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: the function in matlab is this : function ber_c = CalcRepetir(M,n,p,EbNo)
k           = log2(M);
e           = (n-1)/2; 
ber_c       = nchoosek(n,e+1)*p.^(e+1);
%=========================================================================
% Pc = 0; for it=e+1:n Pc = Pc + nchoosek(n,it).*ber_theory.^it.*(1-ber_theory).^(n-it); end
%=========================================================================
semilogy(EbNo,ber_c,'m--','LineWidth',3); hold on
loc = find(EbNo>=2,1,'first');

Comment: Thanks, but it's no good putting this information in comments: please add it to the question!

Comment: i put in the question

Comment: i need so much convert this function to python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python SciPy Possible cases of n choose k](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18488005/python-scipy-possible-cases-of-n-choose-k)

Answer (score 2):

For the actual combinations, see the function [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations).

Calculating the number of combinations is straightforward from the definition, you can use `math.factorial` to help.

Comment: I think the OP wants the count of the number of combinations, rather than the combinations themselves.

Comment: @MarkDickinson: `nchoosek` seems to returns both, depending on the type of the arguments. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Check this out.

```
def nchoosek(n, k):
    if k == 0:
        r = 1
    else:
        r = n/k * nchoosek(n-1, k-1)
    return round(r)
```

Comment: Why do you need recursion here?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more complete answer. You should use itertools.combinations and not the itertools.permutations as combination is very different from permutation.

For instance if you needed all the two element combinations of an array such as [1,2,3,5] the following code will produce the result that you want (equivalent of nchoosek in Matlab)

```
>>> import itertools
>>> all_combos = list(itertools.combinations([1,2,3,5], 2))
>>> print all_combos
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 5), (2, 3), (2, 5), (3, 5)]
```

if You would like all the combinations as a 2d array just convert the tuple list to a numpy array using the following command:

```
>>> all_combos = np.array(list(itertools.combinations([1,2,3,5], 2)))
>>> print all_combos
[[1 2]
[1 3]
[1 5]
[2 3]
[2 5]
[3 5]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Python 3.8, the [`math` module](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/math.html) includes the `comb` method:

```
import math

e=10
n=30
p=2
print(math.comb(n,e+1)*p**(e+1))
```